# Groupping results based on fields - Lucene

Tags: java, lucene

I'm using Lucene 4.10.4. I want to take "n results" from  20 different fields in an efficient way without searching 20 times. If I search using boolean query, we might get all the results in single search. I want to group results based on fields, is there any grouping concept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is:
http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_10_4/grouping/org/apache/lucene/search/grouping/package-summary.html

But in newer versions it only works on DocValues, so you would have to add the field again as a DocValue to be able to group over it. (But maybe in 4.10 it still works with the FieldCache, but I'm not familiar with that)

You can use `GroupingSearch` or maybe `BlockGroupingCollector` to have multiple elements per group and specify how results are ordered within a group.

You have to include the `lucene-grouping` dependency to use it.